# My program successfully compiled and run yet displays wrong output

Tags: java

My program must display whether the answer to the question "Is 10>2" is correct, wrong or the user must have had wrong input. Even if I type "YES" or "NO", it will still display WRONG INPUT. It is a very, very simple program. However, I'm a newbie. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class yesorno{

public static void main (String args[]){

    Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
    String ans;

    System.out.println("Answer with a YES or NO");
    System.out.println("Is 10>2?");
    System.out.print("Answer:");
    ans = answer.next();

    if(ans == "YES"){
        System.out.print("Correct!");
    }

    else if (ans == "NO"){
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("Wrong input!");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(ans == "YES"){
```

You should use [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare strings and not `operator==`

Note that `operator==` will yield true only if the two objects are actually the same object, and it is not the case.

You should replace it to `if(ans.equals("YES")) {` [and do the same for all other conditions in your program]

Comment: @keavy: I added what the condition should be, and also attached a link to the `equals()` method java docs, so you can read more about it.

Comment: Ok, ok. One more thing, are "==" for numbers only?

Comment: @keavy: `operator==` is for checking identity, and not equality. in case of [prmitives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) - identity is equality.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing string comparison in Java using ==, which is generally not recommended, since == does object comparison and not actual string comparison.

Try using the equals() method.

That is, change your code from

```
if(ans == "YES"){
    System.out.print("Correct!");
}

else if (ans == "NO"){
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

to

```
if(ans. equals("YES")){
    System.out.print("Correct!");
}

else if (ans.equals("NO")){
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. One thing, Are "==" for numbers only?